# What exactly is an address in bitcoin

Tags: address, private-key

Here is what I've understood of bitcoin:

- Everybody has a public and private key.
- If A sends bitcoins to B:

  - B is generating an address and sends it to A
  - This addresses are generated for each transaction.
  - A needs to sign something with his private key and B's address

Am I wrong?

If not, I want to understand how this address is computed.

I have read it is a kind of public key computed from private key. That's it? So we can have many public keys which match to a common private key?
I have also read the address is derived from the public key.

Comment: related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/13059/5406

Answer (score 1):

> Everybody has a public and private key.

Everybody is able to generate any number of private keys ("[randomly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSPRNG)") and derive a public key from it.

> If A sends bitcoins to B:
>
> B is generating an address and sends it to A

B *[forms](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address)* an address out of the public key itself derived from a "randomly" generated private key.

> This addresses are generated for each transaction.

Ideally yes, unfortunately (privacy-wise) it's a decision made by the sender. Sending twice to the same address is possible.

> A need to sign something with his private key and B's address

This something is, *[basically](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/OP_CHECKSIG)*, the transaction itself.

EDIT: To answer the question title :-)

> What is physically an address in bitcoin

Some bytes either stored on your hard disk or in memory, which are part of a [transaction](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction) and which are to be interpreted as a [script](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script) describing what conditions should be met to spend the coins "[next to](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#tx)" this address.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, but this is slightly more clear:

- Everybody can generate an *arbitrary amount of private-public keypairs*.
- For A to send bitcoins to B:

  - B generates *a private key, and the corresponding public key*, and its address and sends it to A
  - *For every payment request, address reuse may be avoided for privacy reasons.*
  - A has (at least) one Unspent Output (which is the reference to a previous transaction that sended coins to A).  A's public key matches his address, so with his private key he can sign a transaction saying "I own the coins, I spent them to B's address, which he can spend with his public key matching this address, after signing it with his private key"

An address consists of a checksum (extra few bytes to make sure if one makes a mistake while typing the address, the checksum won't be valid), the network byte (meaning "For use with the main Bitcoin network"), and the hash of a public key. (You can experiment with an example of a hash [here](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256.html). And why a hash is used [in addresses](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/3600))

For one to spend, the public key is revealed and its hash is compared with the address's, and then the signature is verified with the public key.

A private key always maps to only one public key. Usually, there's only one address we can derive from a public key. In reality, a public key is a point something called an elliptic curve. Because there are multiple ways to encode its coordinates, a public key can map to multiple addresses (not because of the hash. Hashing always gives one output)